# Bracket on the side of a fraction only over the numerator or denominator

Tags: vertical-alignment

I've been trying to put a curly bracket next to the denominator of a fraction, something like this

```
\frac{1}{a + b} \} = 1
```

where a + b = 1.

Basically I need to move the bracket down a bit, but v space doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: I find this a bit hard to read, as if you're saying the fraction 1/(a+b) = 1.  I would use `\underbrace` to put the bracket below, as in `\frac{1}{\underbrace{a+b}_{=1}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mathtools` and its `\mathrlap` macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{1}{a + b \mathrlap{\ \} = 1} } 
\]
\end{document}
```

BTW: Next time please post a full minimal example like above. That makes it s lot easier for others to test your code and not get stumped by some missing package you did not mention.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with stacks.  Here, the equation axis remains aligned with the `=` sign, which may be important in some use cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\stackon[-\dp\strutbox]{}{\dfrac{1}{a+b\strut}} \} = 1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\stackon[0pt]{}{\dfrac{1}{\smash{a+b}}} \} = 1
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You were a lot more precise than my answer. I wanted to create something that was as simple as possible without using others strong and useful operators.

Comment: @Sebastiano While a precise solution can be appreciated for its intrinsic beauty, sometimes "better still" is the enemy of "good enough."  So your solution is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of the good previous answer could be using `aligned` with a matrix as in the figure (for the denominator):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{a + b} & \begin{matrix}  & \\ \,\}=1\end{matrix}
\end{aligned}\] 
\end{document}
```